# Reputation in summary tab shows as blank instead of 0, if net result is zero

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page, reputation-summary

On a user's profile summary tab, the reputation amount (+/-) is shown, with the link to the question.

If a user gains 10 reputation for an upvote then it is shown as +10. But when a series of down vote events takes place for the same post, and the reputation reaches 0, it should show 0, but instead it's empty/blank.

Is this a bug or is it done intentionally?

> [image]

Comment: Where is it that you're seeing this? Can you link to it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/741099/nyxynyx?tab=summary

Answer (score 1):

That's most likely because for a while it was at +10/-10 resulting in 0 change. (five downvotes, two upvotes)

Don't think it's bug, though it might be better to just remove items with 0 change from the summary.

Comment: why its not showing 0, while every other changes are shown

Comment: I'd not want items with a zero net result to be removed. Something *did* happen there. Even more, you're almost correct in your math (but this was [a question that was voted on](http://stackoverflow.com/users/741099/nyxynyx?tab=reputation)), and as many as 7 votes were cast. I'd like that post to be listed then. (Maybe even as vote counts, like +2/-5, rather than actual reputation.)

Comment: @TryingTobemyselfRahul probably because the devs thought it's meaningless to show 0 in the column, if that's really the case feel free to start feature request asking to show it even when 0.

Comment: @Arjan it's still showing in the full reputation tab, but in summary I'm not sure we really need to show it.

Comment: Hehe, with that logic, we could get rid of most data in the summary? ;-)

Comment: (Ah, I now see that your match was perfectly right. I actually typed that in my comment first, then for some weird reason thought your example was different and changed my comment. Well, it doesn't change the meaning of my comment though.)

Comment: @Arjan by the way, would you prefer to see +0 or -0? ;)